# Plug-in org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.editors.JpaXmlEditor

Tags: jsf-2.2, maven

Beleza Pessoal, estou com um erro que apareceu agora no eclipse luna, alguém sabe o que pode ser, algum plugin para atualizar? O arquivo persistence.xml nao abre e aparece o erro no titulo

```
Plug-in org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.editors.JpaXmlEditor.

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui was unable to load 
class org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.editors.JpaXmlEditor.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)


org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui (414).
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)


Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.plugin.JptJpaUiPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.clearJpaProjects_(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:356)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.clearJpaProjects(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:345)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
... 150 more
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o problema, os passos que você executa para a apresentação do erro, a relação com as tags que foram incluídas na questão, isso facilitaria a reprodução do problema e sugestão de solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver, valeu pela atenção Bruno, tive que atualizar um plugin, e colocar umas versões não tão novas, provavelmente aconteceu algum conflito, os passos foram:

Help - Install New Software - Work with - Selecionei essa opção abaixo:
http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/luna/1.1

Abriu uma caixa de opções e marquei:

```
Jboss Web and JavaEE Development
```

Instalei e feito a atualização desses componentes, mudei para versões não tão recentes e tudo funcionou.

Valeu

Comment: no meu caso foi o site do JBoss - http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/

ps.: java dá muito problema.. =(